# react-native-firebase/auth signInWithPhoneNumber not sending OTP

Tags: javascript, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have integrated the @react-native-firebase/auth package for signing in with a phone number. I have also whitelisted the domain. But the OTP is not being sent.

Below is the code

```js
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(
          userPhone,
          forceResend,
        );
```

Comment: have you found the solution or work around?

Comment: I was using Spark plan and upgraded to Blaze. This seems to be an issue with quota exceeding. We contacted the Firebase support team.